# Odd behavior from PHP header()

Tags: php, header

I'm trying to write a check to redirect users based on their progress through the sign up process for the site. I have this:

```
if($user = VRComponent::getLogin()) {
    if(VR::exists('vr_user','Signup',"userID={$user->ID}")) {
        $step = VR::select('vr_user','Signup',"userID={$user->ID}");
        $step = intval($step[0]['step']);
        if(!isset($_GET['step']) || $step != intval($_GET['step'])) {
            switch($step) {
                case 1: header("Location: /signup/one"); exit; break;
                case 2: header("Location: /signup/two"); exit; break;
                case 3: header("Location: /signup/three"); exit; break;
                case 4: header("Location: /signup/four"); exit; break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: /account");
        exit;
    }
} else {
    header("Location: /");
    exit;
}
```

The exists and select functions are basically just aliases to mysql functions.
Essentially this checks if the user is logged in. If so, it checks to see if they've completed the sign up process. If not, it checks to see if the "page" get var passed is actually the last page they were on. If not, it redirects them to the correct page.
The logic works, however all external js and css files referenced by the page don't load. The weird thing is they don't throw a 404, instead the only contents of the files are:
`Failed to load source for: https://domain.com/path/to/file/style.css`
The other odd thing is the files don't load even if the condition for the if statement is false. Commenting out the switch statement (even when the if condition is false) allows the files to load, but of course the logic wouldn't be correct then.
I figure it pretty much has to be something simple, but I'm just not seeing it. I'm at the point where I'm about to put my fist through my monitor because the behavior makes no sense to me.
Thanks in advance
-D

Comment: you can leave break; after exit;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** I slept on it and when I woke up I figured out the actual problem (it's amazing what a clear mind can do). Turns out PHP was doing exactly what I was telling it to do. Because I've never been satisfied with any 3rd party PHP framework, I decided to build my own a little while back. One of the things it does is automatically cull together all css and js files used in any given page into single files to reduce the number of http requests. It also mirrors the main page's requires in those css/js files and I have apache set up so it'll execute inline PHP. Therefore, the problem code was being required by the js/css files which was then redirecting to one of the signup pages because $_get['step'] was undefined. This kind of stuff really makes me glad I use my own framework, though. Sure, at times it makes me want to go medieval like a man with an axe on some zombies, but the freedom it affords and the ability to evolve it as I go far outweighs the rage. Not only that, but it makes everything so much easier (when I actually code it right) than any other framework I've used. Maybe someday when I feel it's ready for primetime, I'll release it to the public.

**Old------------------------------------**
After a few more hours of research I fixed it! 
The issue was a redirect loop of sorts. For reasons unknown to me, the external files were being run through the block in my OP from the php file which was then changing the location to one of those redirects.
To fix it I checked for '.css' and '.js' in the php_self and disallowed the redirect if found. Here is the modified code:

```
if($user = VRComponent::getLogin()) {
    if(VR::exists('vr_user','Signup',"userID={$user->ID}")) {
        $step = VR::select('vr_user','Signup',"userID={$user->ID}");
        $step = intval($step[0]['step']);
        $css = stripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.css');
        $js = stripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.js');
        if(!$css && !$js && (!isset($_GET['step']) || $step != intval($_GET['step']))) {
            switch($step) {
                case 1: header('Location: /signup/one');
                    break;
                case 2: header('Location: /signup/two');
                    break;
                case 3: header('Location: /signup/three');
                    break;
                case 4: header('Location: /signup/four'); 
                    break;
            }
        }
    } else
        header("Location: /account");
} else
    header("Location: /");
```

Yes, it's crude, and I'll devise a more elegant solution sooner or later, but for now this'll have to do.
Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you are using a mod-rewrite to handle `signup/*`? If so, you might need to declare a `<base href="APPROPRIATE BASE" />` in the `<head>` of your HTML so that the browser doesn't LOOK in a putative signup folder for css/js =)

Comment: Shad is right.  The browser might be asking for /signup/cssfile.css instead of just /cssfile.css.
Probably mod_rewrite is forwarding every 404 to the frontend script, so you don't see the error either.

Comment: Been mulling over this one with no clear answer in mind and I have to say Shad's answer seems to me to be the best fit currently. What say you Derek, any luck on testing this theory out?

Comment: I thought it might be something like this at first, but I'm using all absolute paths for the external files. Also, the "failed to load source" errors correctly state the fully qualified path to the files, they just don't load.

Comment: @Derek have you double checked your mod-rewrite for the issue Sebastián brought up~? maybe it's too strong/broad.

Comment: All my rewrite rules are very specific and none of them overlap the paths to the other files.

Comment: dang~ sorry i wasn't able to help :(

Comment: It happens to the best of us. I'm usually able to figure this kind of stuff out, but this just has me supremely confused and frustrated.

Comment: Do the external files get loaded when you enter directly to /signup/one instead of being redirected there?

Comment: No. It's all actually the same physical page, it just changes what's displayed in the body based on the "step" var. Like I noted in the OP, the only way I've been able to get the files to load is by commenting out the switch block completely. The odd thing is they load even if the if block wrapping the switch isn't entered, which doesn't make any sense to me at all. I guess the real question is how can code that's never executed effect the overall script?